# If i consider capacitor discharging process..and i take wires resistance zero..put the capacitor in vacuum .. where does all the energy go...?

Tags: energy, capacitance

If i consider capacitor discharging process.and i take wires resistance zero.put the capacitor in vacuum . where does all the energy go?like is it the displacement current .but there's no medium then.or is it the fact that lesser the resistance more the current and so current goes to infinity and the heat released becomes non determinable.

Comment: The heat released can’t exceed the stored energy, which ends up being the finite product of an arbitrarily large power dissipation and an arbitrarily short discharge time. Is this what you’re asking about?

Answer (score 1):

A resistance 0 does not exist, except a superconductor but it would have  an inductance, so the energy would be in the magnetic field and then again in C, , you have a resonant circuit

Comment: yeah but what if i consider ideal situation i know its not allowed by the laws of physics but in high school we study a lot of ideal stuff , but yeah i guess that solves my doubt precisely ..thank you sir